# IBM DB2 for Linux AMD64 does not install on Debian Jessie, installer log suggests issue with IBM-supplied libdb2ure.so

Tags: debian, kvm, db2

I have a ThinkPad T430 with 8 GB RAM and an Intel Core i5 3320M running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7 using kernel 2.6.32-642, and a KVM-QEMU VM running Debian Jessie for AMD64 with kernel 3.16.0-4, and I am trying to install IBM DB2 Advanced Enterprise Server Edition 11.1 (as an IBM employee I can use it without cost for private purposes, training in my case) using X forwarding for graphical interface (which I know it works because from the same command prompt I can launch Synaptic). When I try to launch the official `db2setup` graphical installer I get the splash screen, but then the installer quits.

Reading the installer log file `/tmp/db2setup.err`, the crash is due to a segmentation fault on library `libdb2ure.so`, which is supplied by IBM on the installer package. Googling revealed two possible fixes that didn't work: [adding my machine's hostname to /etc/hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270161/db2-9-7-fails-to-install-with-segmentation-fault) (did that to no effect), and [making sure to install DB2 from a local filesystem](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21681146) (I am doing that). Then I [followed this post](http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/db2-l/db2-9764-bit-installation-ends-abruptly-without-any-message-on-rhel-4053911) and tried making sure all the library's dependencies listed by `readelf` were installed (they are), then I installed the Korn shell (KSH93) from APT (it didn't work).

I would like to explore other possible fixes before going ahead with building another VM running CentOS (DB2 is certified to run on RHEL, not Debian), as I fear running a second VM for my DB2 server would put too much strain on my workstations's RAM.